# Finding the equation of an ellipse using eccentricity

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The ellipse $E$ has eccentricity $\frac{1}{2}$, focus $(0,0)$ with the line $x=−1$ as the corresponding directrix. Find an equation for $E$.

The equation I get is $(x+\frac{1}{3})^2 + y^2=\frac{4}{9}$ which is a circle, radius $\frac{2}{3}$. Is this wrong? I feel it must be because I then have to find the other focus and directrix.

Comment: The equation should be $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac12|x-(-1)| \iff x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{2^2}(x+1)^2 \iff \frac34(x-\frac13)^2 + y^2 = \frac13$$

Comment: The configuration of the focus and directrix is begging for the polar form to be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this step by step.

\begin{align*}
\lvert PF\rvert &= e\,\lvert PL\rvert \\
\lvert PF\rvert^2 &= e^2\,\lvert PL\rvert^2 \\
x^2+y^2 &= \left(\tfrac12\right)^2(x+1)^2 \\
4x^2+4y^2 &= x^2+2x+1 \\
3x^2-2x+4y^2 &= 1 \\
3\left(x^2-2x\cdot\tfrac13+\tfrac19\right) + 4y^2 &= 1+3\cdot\tfrac19 \\
3\left(x-\tfrac13\right)^2 + 4y^2 &= \tfrac43 \\
\tfrac94\left(x-\tfrac13\right)^2 + 3y^2 &= 1 \\
\left(\frac{x-\tfrac13}{\tfrac23}\right)^2 +
\left(\frac{y-0}{\sqrt{\tfrac13}}\right)^2 &= 1
\end{align*}

So the center would be at $(\tfrac13,0)$, the length of the semiaxis in $x$ direction would be $\tfrac23$ and the length of the semiaxis in $y$ direction would be $\sqrt{\tfrac13}$. The grid in the following illustration has distance $\tfrac13$ between the lines.

[image: Figure of ellipse with coordinate axes, grid, foci and directrices]

Note that the above computation heavily relies on the fact that the directrix is vertical, which makes the whole ellipse axis-aligned. Otherwise we'd have to account for rotation, which would complicate things. See [this post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217797/35416) for reading geometric properties of a generic equation. In the case of a focus and directrix description, it would be easier to first transform coordinates to axis-align the directrix, though.

I'm not sure how you obtained your equation, so I can't tell you where you went wrong.