# Finding the equation of hyperbola that passes through $(2,0)$ and has foci points $(2,3)$ and $(1,0)$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

If the hyperbola is given by $$(x-x_0)^2/a^2-(y-y_0)^2/b^2=1$$
and I know that if $F(c,0)$ is a foci point then  $c^2=a^2+b^2$ I can say that in this particular problem $a^2+b^2=1$.Then I plug in the given point and I get $$(2-x_0)^2/a^2-(y_0)^2/1-a^2=1$$
Now I have one equation with two unknowns. Could you please explain how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center of the hyperbola is the midpoint of the segment joining $F_1(2,3),F_2(1,0)$ that is $M\left(\frac32,\frac32\right)\equiv(x_0,y_0)$.

Thus $c^2=MF_1^2$

This is a rotated hyperbola.

---

Edit

$(x_0,y_0)=\left(\frac32,\frac32\right)$

$c^2=MF_1^2=5/2$

$$\frac{\left(2-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{a^2}-\frac{\left(0-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{\frac{5}{2}-a^2}=1$$
solve for $a$

Comment: Can I say that $a^2+b^2=1/2$? for a rotated hyperbola and then plug in the given point and solve for $x_0$ and $y_0$ ?

Comment: @Britanica I added some detail to my answer

Comment: I get four crazy possible values foe $a$ e.g. $$sqrt(10-3sqrt10)/2$$. Is that fine?

Comment: Result is $$\frac{4 \left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{10-3 \sqrt{10}}-\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} \left(y-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Using [A hyperbola as a constant difference of distances](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49517/a-hyperbola-as-a-constant-difference-of-distances) if $P(h,k)$ is an arbitrary point of the required hyperbola,

$$2a=|\sqrt{(h-2)^2+(k-3)^2}-\sqrt{(h-1)^2+(k-0)^2}|, a>0$$

As the hyperbola passes through $(2,0);$

$$2a=|\sqrt{(2-2)^2+(0-3)^2}-\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(0-0)^2}|=?$$

Comment: But if $a=1$ that means that $b=0$. How can that happen?

Comment: @Britanica, How $b=0?$ Have you reached the equation of the hyperbola?

Comment: If $F_1(1;0)$ doesn't that mean $a^2+b^2=1$ ?

Comment: @Britanica,  $$2ae=\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(3-0)^2}=\sqrt{10}$$ and $$2a=1$$  $$\implies e=?$$  Finally $$b^2=a^2(e^2-1)=\dfrac{10-1}4$$